# Dynamic radio and checkbox data retrieval and labeling in tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I built a GUI with tkinter that looks like this. I have a dataframe with 180,000 contacts and these are the 2 filters I use to sort them. What I want is the label that currently says 12345 to show the no. of contacts meeting the aforementioned criterias.

I already have a function that caluclates that, how to make the end result display in this label dynamically (i.e. without the user pressing enter/ok). In case this is not possible, I will add a button.

[image: GUI created with tkinter]

Comment: You can bind a command to your radiobuttons.

Comment: Thanks, I binded the same command to all checkboxes, radios and the textboxes (passes all values to a function). A little complicated but works well. Do you think there's a neater way to do that?

Comment: I would probably do the same. There are alternatives like binding `<Button-1>` to the whole frame, or even scheduling a constant check by using `root.after`, but i rather be precise than overdo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely want to "bind" some callback methods to "events" such as clicking a checkbutton and/or radiobutton.

For example, based on [this page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm), it looks like the `Checkbutton` widget has a `command` parameter, which you could set equal to a callback function.

You might try writing something like this:

```py
def update_label(event):
    # code to update label

c = Checkbutton(
    text="Select Regions",
    [...other args...],
    command=update_label
)
```

Comment: `command` should be a callable, not a string. you need to remove the double quotes

Comment: Good catch. Fixed.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I did. The function is a bit slow, so I'm gonna optimise that but apart from that this is perfect. Thank you!